# Bulk Insert - Does the file need to be accessible to database server or local machine?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

My question is about where I should put a file I need to use in a BULK INSERT command in MS SQL.

I have a database running on a server. I run queries on this through an ODBC connection from my machine on the same network. I want to create a stored procedure that will use Bulk Insert to import data from a .txt file and then execute this stored procedure from my machine (from clicking a button in  an Excel sheet).

I'm no expert on how SQL Server actually works to say the least so I have what I imagine is a very basic question for someone who does. Does the .txt file used in the Bulk Insert need to be in a location that can be read by:

a) my machine e.g. on it's local hard disk

or

b) on a location that can be read by the database server e.g. somewhere on the network that it can access

I'm not sure if my local machine or the server is actually opening the file. I would assume it's the server, but I'd like to be sure!

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not on the server computer, then you will need to make sure SQL Server has access to the file.  This becomes a permissions issue.  In particular, the permission you need to look at is the log on account for the SQL Server service.  Open the services control panel, locate the SQL Server service and check the log on account in the properties section.

As a general rule, it's not a good idea to give too many network permissions to the SQL Server service account because this can allow hackers access to resources outside the server computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `BULK INSERT` command from T-SQL then the name of the 'data_file' can be a local filename or an UNC path, local that is to the SQL Server machine running the query. You can put the file to import from on a share hosted on the SQL Server machine or on any other share in the network the SQL Server has access to.